# Distributional Solutions to $xu'=0$

Tags: distribution-theory

I want to solve the differential equation $xu' = 0$ for some distribution $u \in \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. It seems apparent that the solution $u$ should be of the form $u = c_1 + c_2H$ where $c_1,c_2$ are constants, and $H$ is the Heaviside function. Is there any way I can prove that these are the only solutions rigorously?

Comment: Abstracting a part of the issue to show that it's pretty easy: given a smooth function $f$, show that any distribution $u$ such that $f\cdot u=0$ must be supported just on the zero-set of $f$...